# Insert element into vector of string sets c++

Tags: c++, vector, set

How to insert a element into vector of sets. Set is structure where I can not use indexing, or `begin()`, `end()`. I could only use `insert()`, and `erase()` methods. And how is this structured in memory? 
This part of code is not working, it shows error in `timovi[i].insert('A')`, also in `timovi.insert('A');` I am trying to print those elements to. I have also included `sets`, `vector`s and everything that is used in programm.

For explanation,
 
`timovi` means teams, `br_timova` is number of teams and `vel_tim` is number of elements in `set`.

```
std::vector<std::set<std::string>> timovi;
     for(int i (0); i < br_timova ; i++){
            timovi.push_back(std::set<std::string>());
            for(int j (0); j < vel_tim ; j++ ){
                timovi[i].insert( 'A' );
            }
        }


        for(int i (0); i < timovi.size();i++){
            for(auto x : timovi[i]) std::cout<<x<<" ";
            std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
```

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: _Set is structure where I can not use indexing, or begin(),end()._ 1) Indexing for `set` is not needed, hence why it isn't available. 2) You **can** use `begin`, and `end` iterators. Did you try looking at the documentation of `set`, before making such a claim?

Comment: `'A'` is a `char` whereas `timovi[i].insert(...)` is expecting an `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. @G.M. Yes,I have looked in the documentation, that's actually why I have explained what I can or can't use. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
timovi[i].insert('A')
```

has an issue that can be simplified to:

```
std::set<std::string> s;
s.insert( 'A' );
```

problem is that `std::set::insert()` in this case expects `std::string` but you  provide single char `'A'` and there is no implicit conversion from `char` to `std::string`. You can create string from a single char:

```
s.insert( std::string( 1, 'A' ) ); // one char
```

or simply using string literal:

```
s.insert( "A" ); // note double quotes
```

or maybe you suppose to have `std::set<char>` instead.

Comment: Thanks. It helps me a lot. (Y)